# Corrupted FBX Binary File

Tags: c++, fbx

I am new to using the FBX SDK and I am trying to convert an OBJ file to an FBX ASCII file in C++. However, when running the following code it outputs a Binary FBX file and the file seems to be incorrect/"corrupted." The reason I say it is corrupted is because when I insert it into the FBX conversion program that Autodesk provides, it says the input binary file I got as an output from my program is corrupted. Can anyone help me solve this issue please? Thank you in advance.

```
//Creates a SDK manager
FbxManager* fbxmanager = FbxManager::Create();

//Set the Input/Output Settings for the SDK Manager
//EXP_ = export settings; IMP_ = import setting 
FbxIOSettings* ios_settings = FbxIOSettings::Create(fbxmanager, IOSROOT);
ios_settings->SetBoolProp(EXP_ASCIIFBX, true);
fbxmanager->SetIOSettings(ios_settings);

//Creates a Scene
FbxScene* fbxscene = FbxScene::Create(fbxmanager, "");

//Creates an importer object
FbxImporter* fbximporter = FbxImporter::Create(fbxmanager, "");

//Path to the obj file
const char* obj_path = "objs/airboat.obj";

//Path to the saved fbx file
const char* fbx_path = "fbxs/global_mesh.fbx";

//Initilaize the Importer Object with the path and name of the file
bool import_stat = fbximporter->Initialize(obj_path, -1, fbxmanager->GetIOSettings());

import_stat = fbximporter->Import(fbxscene);

//Creates an exporter object
FbxExporter* fbxexporter = FbxExporter::Create(fbxmanager, "");

//Initilaize the Exporter Object with the path and name of the file

bool export_stat = fbxexporter->Initialize(fbx_path, -1,fbxmanager->GetIOSettings());

export_stat = fbxexporter->Export(fbxscene);
```

EDIT: Sorry forgot to provide debugging output:

All boolean functions result in true.

Comment: I assume those bools the functions are returning are to indicate success or failure. You should be checking them to see if something went wrong.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Edited the post. The boolean functions result in all true.